# Can we Re-Insert deleted auto increment ID

Tags: sql-server-2012

scenario is I have 10 Ids if I delete 1 id like 9th

then again how will I insert data in 9th id...? when IDs are auto increment

Comment: auto increment ids are not supposed to behave like that.

Comment: You don't. Don't mess with the auto.increment ids. Just leave them be.

Comment: Stop caring about gaps.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated in the comments; you don't want to do this.

If you want to use these numbers for some purpose (such as for ordering by), create a new int column in the table. Never use the auto ID!